# Delphi DDE Callback

Tags: delphi, dde

I would like to receive Item to my DDE Client in Delphi every time when Item is changing. I know that is function DDE Callback. Can you tell me how I should use it?
Hawe you maybe some code examples?

--
Pawel

Comment: Wow, DDE, how very 20th century. Isn't it time to move on to something more robust. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/26/1763683.aspx

Comment: What kind of item are you trying to monitor exactly?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, in principle I agree, but sometimes you have no control over the other side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it really has to be DDE:

- Place a TDdeClientConv and a TDdeClientItem onto a form.
- Connect the TDdeClientItem to the TDdeClientConv.
- Set the ServerApplication, DdeService, DdeTopic and DdeItem properties according to your needs.
- Implement the OnChange event of the TDdeClientItem. The current value can be read from the Text and/or Lines property.